# How can Wireshark view all network traffic?

Tags: networking, wireshark

Suppose I run Wireshark on my PC, and I'm connected to a router, how can Wireshark know about all the traffic from that router?

Isn't the router supposed to isolate each client and route only their own data to and from themselves? What actually happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suppose I run Wireshark on my PC, and I'm connected to a router, how can Wireshark know about all the traffic from that router?

If you have a router that's connected to multiple LANs, then Wireshark, running on a machine connected to one of those LANs, *can't* know about all the traffic from the router unless the router has been configured to, for traffic that would otherwise not be routed to that LAN, send a copy of the packet on that LAN.

If you're talking about a *LAN switch*, so that everything plugged into the switch is on the same LAN, the situation is similar - the switch would have to be configured to send copies of traffic to the switch port into which the machine running Wireshark is plugged.

The ability to do that is a common feature in higher-end switches; a port can be configured to be a "mirror port".  See [the Wireshark Wiki page on Ethernet capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) for details.  I don't know whether any routers provide an equivalent of "port mirroring".

Answer (score 1):

The isolation of packets to ports is the functionality of a switch. 
A hub sends the packets to all ports.

But your router acts also as a switch. You can place a device in front of the router and sniff from there. This device needs to be a hub, a switch with a monitor port or a splitter. 
Or you can use arp spoofing to manipulate the arp tables of the computers in the network. But that is mostly considered as an attack.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Actually, layer-2 switches know nothing of packets. Traffic on a LAN is switched by the layer-2 frames, and hub replicate frames out all ports, not layer-3 packets. The packets are encapsulated in the frames, and it is the frames which are used in LAN switching. Routers strip off the frames and switch packets between networks.